# Create histogram using seaborn when frequency and binwidth are given

Tags: python, histogram, seaborn, frequency

when I am given the frequency and the binwidth, how can I display this data in a histogram?
For instance:
time  Frequency
0-10           3
11-30          4
30+            5

I chose variable binwidths on purpose and I also want the last bin to include everything greater than 30.
I cannot really figure out how I can do this with sns.distplot().
Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: You can't do it with `distplot`. But you can just plot a bar chart, e.g. `plt.bar(time, freq)`

Comment: Seems like I have no choice. I just used Pyroot. Thank you for your help.